# new error, Error in plot.new() : attempt to plot on null device

Tags: r, plot

Can anyone help with this error I'm getting, I'm currently on mac.

```
lob=read.csv("~/Desktop/data.csv")
lob
mlm.lob=glm(location~crusher+cutter+rostrum+as.factor(sex),data=lob,family="binomial")
mlm.lob
plot(mlm.lob)
```

> Error in plot.new() : attempt to plot on null device

Comment: hard to see how this could happen, but: run `quartz()` first?  Can we have results of `sessionInfo()` please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Execute dev.off() before trying to plot your graph. Is this doesn't work you can set your relative figure sizes/plot sizes by setting par(). Look up the description by typing in help(par).